# Implement filter options in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm fairly new to Gatsby and React and I couldn't find an answer to my problem.
I want to be able to have filtering options on the home of my website that allow the user to display only content relevant to that filter.

Let's say my posts are recipes and they are categorized by type: main, snack and dessert.
I want a filter, can be a button or a drop-down it doesn't matter, and when the user selects it I will display only the items relevant. Ideally I'm going to have multiple filters, around 4-5 for different properties of the frontmatter of my posts .

From what I understand it's not really something I can do with graphql because after build I cannot access it anymore so I was seeking some advice from more experienced devs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a small set of posts, I think you can make a search component that get all the posts & then use something like [`js-search`](https://github.com/bvaughn/js-search) or [`flexsearch`](https://github.com/nextapps-de/flexsearch) to index them.

In a non-page component (not in `src/pages` folder), you can use [StaticQuery](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/) to get all the posts' info.

Say you have this graphql query result:

```
data: {
  allMarkdownRemark: {
    edges: [{
      node: {
        id: '1234-1233...',
        fields: {
          slug: '/hello/'
        },
        frontmatter: {
          title: 'hello',
          tags: [ 'go', 'js' ]
        }
      }
    }, {
      node: {
        id: ...
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Then you can index & search for post, say, with js-search:

```
const posts = data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({ node }) => node) // unwrap edges

const postIndex = new JsSearch.Search('id')
postIndex.addIndex(['frontmatter', 'tags']) // index node.frontmatter.tags
postIndex.addIndex(['frontmatter', 'title'])
postIndex.addDocuments(posts) // add data to array

const results = postIndex.search('go')
console.log(results) // [{ id: '1234-1233...', frontmatter: { title: 'hello', tags: [ 'go', 'js' ]}}]
```

Then you can store this result in, say, the component's state & render the results as posts.

---

Gatsby's doc also has a [guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-search/) on adding search to your site, though I think the `js-search` part is a bit overwhelming.